# What does it mean 'doctor on theme'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean 'doctor on theme'? ([YouTube -03:19](https://youtu.be/KZp5LVQyCxo?t=199)) - according to listening as well as YouTube subtitles.

I have found nothing about it on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misheard the narraror, and/or the subtitles are incorrect. He actually says:

> ... and there's a doctor on **scene**.

"On scene" means "on the premises," i.e. there is a doctor present at the location where the injury occurred.